# Jasmine unit test with mouse event

Tags: jasmine

I'm very new to unit test and want to use Jasmine for unit testing mouse events, something like

```
$('.el').mousedown(function() {
    $(this)[0].dragging = true;  
});
$('.el').mousemove(function() {
    if ( $(this)[0].dragging ) {
        $(this).addClass("dragging");
    }
});
$('.el').mouseup(function() {
    $(this)[0].dragging = false;
    $(this).removeClass("dragging");   
});
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/vRWzz/11/) of how it might work.

My question is how to do the unit test for each function here.

Answer (score 0):

The functions ought to be named functions in $scope. Then you could simply call the function in your test and verify that the element had the class removed/added as expected.